# referencing multiple labels by name

Tags: swift, uilabel

i have a label outlet e.g.

```
infoLabel.text = "\(windowText)"
```

i know i can update the label by changing the text within " " also the value in the variable  **windowText**

but i have multiple labels e.g.

```
text1 = "this is text 1"
text2 = "this is text 2"
text3 = "this is text 3"
```

i want to be able to update **infoLabel** to reference one of text1,text2, text3 based on a counter which increases by  the press of a UIbutton, but i cant seem to get it to work.

so if
   generalCounter = 3

how can make my label reference the string named text(counterGeneral)
and if pressed again and generalCounter is now 4, the label would now need to reference text(4).

Comment: Use an array instead of separate variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **create** a **array** of **strings**:

```
let texts : [String] = [/* Your strings... */]
```

Then in your ***Interface Builder action update your label*** accordingly:

```
// The function with is called when a press of your UIButton occur
@IBAction updateLabel(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Verify there are a next string 
    if generalCounter + 1 < texts.count {

        generalCounter += 1
        infoLabel.text = texts[generalCounter]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Outlet Collection, an array of UILabels to go through each one simply 
while keeping a counter for how many to change text for

[image: Outlet Collection]